# Exiting from main page skipping the login page in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am actually working on the Flutter Application where I navigate from the Login page to the Main Page. But when I Press the back Button it goes to the Login Page that it should not do so.
Can anyone suggest to me what to do from one route(Main Page) to exit the project on back pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

`Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('myMainPage', (r) => r == null);`

This way your `LoginScreen` will be removed from the navigation stack and trying to go back from your main page will close your application.